# How to make eslint "more strict" about inferred any types?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I want to make eslint issue a warning everywhere where there is an inferred any type.
Is there a rule for that?
My motivation is code as follows:

```js
try {
  // do something
catch (error /* (local var) error: any */) {
  // error.message can be undefined and I would like to know without having to manually hover every var
  sendErrorToApi(error.message)
}
```

Comment: have you tried `noImplicitAny` in `tsconfig.json->compilerOptions`?

Comment: Yes, I also have `strict` enabled, which sets is already, I guess.
As I understand, `noImplicityAny` only triggers a warning for function arguments, right?
I want to be warned everywhere there is an `any`.

Comment: For this specific use case, TS 4.4 offers a solution: Defaulting to the unknown Type in Catch Variable https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#use-unknown-catch-variables.

Comment: That helps a lot already! Thank you, mate!